# Paypal returning empty QueryDict - Django

Tags: python, django, paypal

I'm adding PayPal to my project website. I'm using IPN and at the moment it looks like it works fine apart from the fact that when I return to the merchant's page (paypal_return or paypal_cancel) it doesn't post back the transaction information, I can only see an empty "" in my {{ post }} and {{ get }}.
No errors or anything, just that in the page.

Here is my code on GitHub.  https://github.com/IreneG5/spss_online

Any idea why the information is not posted back to my template?

Thanks in advance!

**PayPal return page**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
    {% block content %}
       <p>Your transaction has been completed, and a receipt for your purchase has been emailed to you. You may log into your account at www.paypal.com to view details of this transaction.</p>
    <h2>POST</h2>
    {{ post }}
    <h2>GET</h2>
    {{ get }}
{% endblock %}
```

**Products.php** (Where the PayPal buttons are shown)

```
{% for product in products %}
    <tr>
      <td ><b>{{ product.name }}</b>
      </td>
      ...
      <td>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
          {{ product.paypal_form.sandbox }} <!-- .render for production-->
          {% else %}
               -
         {% endif %}
       </td>
     </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

**Settings**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_forms_bootstrap',
    'paypal.standard.ipn',
    'home',
    'accounts',
    'paypal_store',
    'products',
]

SITE_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'
PAYPAL_NOTIFY_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1/a-very-hard-to-guess-url/'
PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL = 'irene.g5555-facilitator@gmail.com'
```

**Models**

```
class Product(models.Model):
code = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="")
name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
osystem = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="")
description = models.TextField()
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
license_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=license_types, default="1 year")

# Passes the info needed for the PaypalPaymentForm to create
# the button and required HTML when we render the template
@property
def paypal_form(self):
    paypal_dict = {
        "business": settings.PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL,
        "amount": self.price,
        "currency": "EUR",
        "item_name": "%s-%s" % (self.pk, uuid.uuid4()),
        "notify_url": settings.PAYPAL_NOTIFY_URL,
        "return_url": "%s/paypal-return/" % settings.SITE_URL,
        "cancel_return": "%s/paypal-cancel/" % settings.SITE_URL
    }

    return PayPalPaymentsForm(initial=paypal_dict)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

**Views**

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.shortcuts import render


@csrf_exempt
def paypal_return(request):
    args = {'post': request.POST, 'get': request.GET}
    return render(request, 'paypal/paypal_return.html', args)


def paypal_cancel(request):
    args = {'post': request.POST, 'get': request.GET}
    return render(request, 'paypal/paypal_cancel.html', args)
```

**urls for paypal**

```
url(r'^a-very-hard-to-guess-url/', include(paypal_urls)),
url(r'^paypal-return', paypal_views.paypal_return),
url(r'^paypal-cancel', paypal_views.paypal_cancel),
```

Comment: Post the relevant code here, not in Github or some other site.

Comment: Updated with relevant code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have exhaustively searched the internet with no success ensure you have completed the following using the PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL from paypal:

## log into sanbox.paypal.com

## settings -> website payments -> website preferences -> auto return on : http://xxxxxxxx.ngrok.io -> save

## settings -> website payments -> website preferences -> payment data transfer -> yes

without these settings configured you will successfully get an empty query dict. When you update these settings for the PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL account you should now get the pay_pal_dict you are after :)

Answer (score 0):

As per the [django-paypal documentation](https://django-paypal.readthedocs.io/en/stable/standard/ipn.html#testing),

> If you are attempting to test this in development, using the PayPal sandbox, and your machine is behind a firewall/router and therefore is not publicly accessible on the internet (this will be the case for most developer machines), PayPal will not be able to post back to your view. You will need to use a tool like https://ngrok.com/ to make your machine publicly accessible, and ensure that you are sending PayPal your public URL, not localhost, in the notify_url, return and cancel_return fields.

However, I've found that you will get an empty query dictionary if you are using a regular Paypal account (instead of a business account) as the `PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL`. To force paypal to send you the data in the query dictionary, you have to add `"rm": 2,` to your paypal dictionary like so (in your case):

```py
def paypal_form(self):
    paypal_dict = {
        "business": settings.PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL,
        "amount": self.price,
        "currency": "EUR",
        "item_name": "%s-%s" % (self.pk, uuid.uuid4()),
        "notify_url": settings.PAYPAL_NOTIFY_URL,
        "return_url": "%s/paypal-return/" % settings.SITE_URL,
        "cancel_return": "%s/paypal-cancel/" % settings.SITE_URL,
        "rm": 2
    }
```

According to [the Paypal documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx-websitestandard-htmlvariables/#paypal-checkout-page-variables):

> 0. All shopping cart payments use the GET method.
> 1. The buyer's browser is redirected to the return URL by using the GET method, but no payment variables are included.
> 2. The buyer's browser is redirected to the return URL by using the POST method, and all payment variables are included.